# min-height in firefox not working

Tags: firefox, height, css

I'm having a issue with the min-height in firefox, I'm trying to put it at 100% but it is not working. In Chrome it works perfectly.

My code is:

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../css/main.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="header">Here is the header</div>
            <div class="content ">Here is the content</div>
            <div class="footer">Here is the footer</div>
        </div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

And the css file is

```
.header {
    height:160px;
}

.content{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;   
}

.footer{
    margin: -215px auto 0 0; 
    height: 55px;
}
```

All I'm trying to do is to keep the footer at the bottom of the page, in Chrome it is working, but in firefox it takes no height for the content. 
I've been looking for the solution and in many people say to put

```
#page{min-height:100%;} 
html, body{min-height:100%;}
```

but it makes the same, it still works in chrome but not in firefox.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're just trying to keep the footer at the bottom you could use

```
 .footer{
 position:fixed; /*or absolute, or whatever*/
 bottom:0px;
 height: 55px;
 }
```

Comment: It works!, I don't know how I didn't think about it before.

Thank you!